# Color Mapping Section

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

i just wonder how people make color map sections in their own websites with markers  !! 
please check this website in the map section [HERE](http://leitschiff.de/)

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google map API supports styling of the maps.

See *https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling*

And there is also a wizard for creating the style JSON (*see http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter*)

Finally there is a whole community creating custom styles which you can use directly (*see http://snazzymaps.com/*)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to style your map.. here is the easiest way..after you design.. you can copy your code  located at the right side
http://software.stadtwerk.org/google_maps_colorizr/#road.highway/all/224422/on